# Check for update from apk (btn in the apk or other way)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have the simple android app which i develop with ionic. For updating it i just upload apk with new versionCode in manifest file to google play. Is there a way to notify users if the new version is available or insert button "check for updates" to my app? Maybe there is a google play API method which returns a versionCode of the current apk or others ways to do it.
Is there a direct link to the updating my upp (like a button "Update" in Playlay Market app)?
Thanks.

Comment: you can refer this https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WVersionManager

Comment: no, i cant. i develop app with ionic (angularjs).